# wordpress redirect to homepage and seo

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I've created a website (html, css, etc) with 5-6 pages in it, lets say on **example.com**

Now I have to add many additional pages, and I'm not sure if is better to use **WordPress** or add all of these pages as **pure HTML**.

If I will use WordPress, I will install it on a subdirectory like **example.com/page**.

Wordpress with "permalink" can be useful, but in this case I should set a redirect from the wordpress homepage to my html homepage. For example:

```
When someone go on **example.com/page** (wordpress home) 
will be redirected to **example.com** (html homepage)

Instead, if someone go on **example.com/page/my-page**
should see the wordpress page normally.
```

Its that possibile? Which is the best solution for SEO (html static pages, or wordpress with redirect to homepage, separate sitemap, etc)?

Comment: is that ok if you can do this in cpanel??

Comment: what you expecting is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using is_home() function or is_front_page() depending how you set the settings.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){
    /** your code for redirecting to html home page. **/
}
?>
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: thanks, where should I put this code to redirect only the home of wp but not the pages?

Comment: in your theme's header.php. Make sure to write appropriate redirecting code inside the brackets ( where I have put a comment ).